# How do I deploy a Gulp project?

Tags: gulp

I started using Gulp in my projects, but I'm having a bit of trouble deploying them.

I'm trying to deploy them using Netlify, but I'm getting an error saying "build task never definied". Do I need to create this task inside my gulpfile? If so, how do I do that?

```
7:59:22 PM: Task never defined: build
```

Comment: `gulp.task("taskName", funcName)` in your gulpfile. Then call `gulp taskName` from the command line

Comment: I know how to create a task. What I want to know is what write inside the build task.

Comment: Sorry! Maybe I'm still not understanding. It's just a function named "build" that does whatever you want.

Comment: It possible to share the code @ViniciusBortoletto, it would help us look on it.